# Is there a way to convert a string to an array in java?

Tags: java

I want to convert this String:

```
String s = "[\"val1\", \"val2\", \"val3\"]";
```

to an array or an ArrayList (without regex and split). It's from a Database, and it's generic. It's also possible to have commas inside the high quotes.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hello, did you try regex ?

Comment: yes, I have a solution with regex. My question is if there is an easy solution to do this in java? @Mickael

Comment: why do you ask if it's possible if you already have a solution..

Comment: because it's about if there is a better solution than parsing it with regex and creating an array. Maybe there is a good library or a method. It looks like String[] toString... (same format)

Comment: *it's about if there is a better solution than parsing it with regex and creating an array* - and we are supposed to guess this when you ask "is this possible"?

Comment: Have you tried using the split method in the String class? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String- . You can use it like String[] array = s.split(",");

Comment: @fpezzini he said "without regex and split"...

Comment: Thanks @Calaf, sorry I had misread it. 
OP: Why can't you use either split method or regex? Those are the easiest and fastest options available.

Comment: It is JSON so a JSON library or using the Java Scripting API is all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no java API that would directly parse this list.

This snippet would work for this String:

```
    String s = "[\"val1\", \"val2\", \"val3\"]";
    String[] arr = s.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split("\\s*,\\s*");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

If the string contains `[` or `]` somewhere else, then the snippet above won't work.

I suggest to figure out what is this. Is this a JSON array? Then use a JSON parser. Is this a csv with additional `[` and `]`? Then use a CSV parser.

Comment: *Is this a JSON array?* - it is

Answer (score 1):

```
String json = "[\"val1\", \"val2\", \"val3\"]";
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(json);
List<Object> objects = jsonarray.toList();
```

Thanks to @TamasRev

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way using Regex.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class T1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String REGEX = "\\b([\\w]+)\\b";
        String INPUT = "[\"val1\", \"val2\", \"val3\"]";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);   // get a matcher object
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

        while(m.find()) {
            myList.add(m.group());
        }

        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **String tokenizer** and set as delimiters `" \",[]"`.
This is my example. I've used an array, but it's very simple to convert it in a ArrayList if you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "[\"val1\", \"val2\", \"val3\"]";

    String delims = " \",[]";

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, delims);
    
    System.out.println("Num of Token = " + st.countTokens());
    String[] myArr= new String[st.countTokens()];
    
    
    for(int i=0; i<myArr.length && st.hasMoreTokens(); i++)
        myArr[i]=st.nextToken();
    
    //output
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArr));
}
```

Your output will be:

> Num of Token = 3
>
> [val1, val2, val3]